# How add a control as the first element to the container

Tags: sapui5

I have a Dialog which contains a Fragment as below :

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
  <Panel
    id="idPanel">
    <Label
      text="Name"
      width="100%"/>
    <Input
      value="{model>/Name}"/>
  </panel>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

I try to add a MessageStrip above a Label.

For that I use addContent and placeAt as below:

```
var oMsgStrip = new sap.m.MessageStrip("msgStrip", { text : "hello !" });
var oPanel = sap.ui.getCore().byId("idPanel");
oMsgStrip.placeAt(oPanel, "first");
oPanel.addContent(oMsgStrip);
```

But it doesn't work, `oMsgStrip` is added as the last element to the Panel.
How can I do, to add a control as the first element to the container ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `insertContent(oContent, iIndex)`of Panel
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Panel.html#insertContent